# How to use same notification on Background Foreground in APNS

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

Im developing APNS. 
When I send APNS, provide url and move the url.
APNS was succeed but When The app was running, it couldn't receive notification on foreground. 
However on the background, it's work. when it's on foreground 
it just move to url without notification.
Could you help me..?

```
    - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
    UIApplicationState state = [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationState;
    BOOL state_active = (state == UIApplicationStateActive);
    dic_apns = [userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"];

    // alert export
    NSString * msg = [dic_apns objectForKey:@"alert"];
    NSString * eventcode = [userInfo objectForKey:@"eventcode"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue :msg forKey:@"push_msg"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue :eventcode forKey:@"eventcode"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

    NSLog(@"APNS : msg=%@ | eventcode=%@", msg , eventcode);
    [self goto_link];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:0];

}
-(void) goto_link{

    NSString * eventcode = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"eventcode"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", _MAIN_URL, _PUSH_PARAM, eventcode]];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    ViewController* main = (ViewController *)  self.window.rootViewController;

    if (!main.webview_sin )
    {
        NSLog(@"main.webView  is nil!!!");
    }

    [main.webview_sin loadRequest:request];
}
```

Comment: check state of application in didRecieveRemoteNotification according to that either send local notification or show alert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> when it's on foreground it just move to url without notification

This is the expected behaviour. Notifications aren't shown if your app is running.

You could instead use a `UIAlertController` to show the message to the user

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo 
{
    if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive)        
    {               
        UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController
                          alertControllerWithTitle:@"Notification"
                          message:/* Get the message from APS */
                          preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
        UIAlertAction *cancelAction = [UIAlertAction 
        actionWithTitle:@"Dismiss"
                  style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel
                handler:^(UIAlertAction *action)
                {
                    //Do Nothing
                }];
        [alertController addAction:cancelAction];
        [/*pick an appropriate view controller */ presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }    
}
```

<sub>Some code was adapted from [here](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2014/09/05/uialertcontroller-changes-in-ios-8.html)</sub>

Comment: Thank you for your help. But I need to notificate on top bar not alert or dialog.. Could you help me again..?

Comment: There isn't a build in view for the top bar. You'll have to build one yourself or use a third party library.